# Does this linear system even have a solution? 2×3

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$$\begin{aligned} x + 2y + kz &= 1 \\ 2x + ky + 8z &= 3\end{aligned}$$

The assignment is to find values of $k$ that make the system have a unique solution (which is impossible, so that's okay), have no solution at all and have infinite solutions. I don't even know what logic to use in this scenario and had no luck with research. I'd be very thankful to whoever helps me with this.

Answer (score 1):

$k = 4$ gives no solutions. Every other value of $k$ gives infinitely many solutions, because the matrix
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & k \\ 2 & k & 8 \end{bmatrix} $$
has rank $1$ for $k = 4$, and rank $2$ for $k \neq 4$.

Another way to look at it: solve the first equation for $x$ to obtain
$$ x = 1 - 2y - kz. $$
Then substitute this into the second equation. You get
$$ (k - 4)y + (8-2k)z = 1. $$
Observe that if $k = 4$, this second equation makes no sense. But if $k \neq 4$, the second equation just gives the equation of some line on the $y-z$ plane.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this basic result:

> An non-homogeneous linear system $Ax=b$ has solutions if & only if the matrix $A$ and the augmented matrix $(A|x)$ have the same rank. Furthermore, in this case, the common rank is the codimension of the (affine) space of solutions.